# Unity: Why do my normals flip during an animation?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, normals, bug

This problem boggles my mind. I have an animation running on a face object (imported from Blender). At a few points in the animation, the normals switch direction! It causes the mesh to blink.

Of course this animation won't work in its current state. Even odder, I slowed down the animation sample in Unity to 1 so I could isolate the frames it happens on. There are no keyframes on the face when this happens!

What could be causing this? It only happens on this one animation. I can't find anything with extensive web searching. I've also tried recalculating normals and applying transformations, but it doesn't help.

---

These screen shots depict the same two frames, one frame before it happens (left) and the frame when it happens (right), just from different angles.

[image: front view]

[image: back view]

[image: side view]

I'd very much appreciate any input or guidance to fixing this!

Comment: Check your keyframes for backwards normals. Even if the moment they flip isn't on a keyframe, that might just be when the interpolation between two keys passes the halfway mark.

Comment: any good? http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/591105/why-does-half-my-model-flip-when-i-animate-it.html

Comment: the interpolation sounds like a good lead, you should check and see if you have any skale keys in the negatives.

Answer (score 1):

I 'think' I know what this is.
This is not about the normals, it's about the choice of Binormal and Tangent vectors that the mesh exporter plugin chose - they are usually selected based on UV and don't consider the Winding Order of the polygon: the Binormal and Tangent have the wrong handedness sometimes, and if I remember correctly, there is a way we can detect and flip it in the shader.
If I'm completely off track, it's still probably a bug in the exporter, not a bug in the engine.